# Finding maximum node depth of an xml dom tree

Tags: java, xml, dom, depth

How do I find the maximum node depth of an xml file using dom in java?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/578790/XML/Finding-maximum-node-depth-xml

Comment: You traverse the branches and count the levels until you reach a leaf.